# Taking a list of strings and making a new list with each individual string as a sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to make a function that takes a list of strings (a string with characters separated by commas if that makes a difference - see example) and make a new list with each of those individual strings into a sublist. I think (or hope) this is fairly easy and can maybe be accomplished with one line (under a for loop) but cannot figure it out.

For example:

```
  List = ['a, b, c', 'hello, 1, 2, 3', '7, 8, hi']
  function(List) = [['a, b, c'], ['hello, 1, 2, 3'], ['7, 8, hi']]
```

Currently, my function looks like this:

```
    result = []
   for string in L:
       ?????
   return result
```

But I don't know what to put in the ???? line. I've tried things like result.append(list(string)) and others but they do not give me what I am looking for.

Thank you!

Comment: `[[item] for item in List]` (at least this is what your expected output should be - although I'm not sure this is what you really want)?

Comment: `result.append(string)` would do...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like this, using a list comprehension inside a function:

```
def make_sub(seq):
    return [[elt] for elt in seq]


seq = ['a, b, c', 'hello, 1, 2, 3', '7, 8, hi']
print(make_sub(seq))
```

#### output:

```
[['a, b, c'], ['hello, 1, 2, 3'], ['7, 8, hi']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> foo = ['a, b, c', 'hello, 1, 2, 3', '7, 8, hi']
>>> map(lambda x: x.split(", "), foo)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['hello', '1', '2', '3'], ['7', '8', 'hi']]
>>>
```

Comment: Rather than a list, the `map` function is gonna return a `map` object, so it's needed to cast that to a `list` by using `>>> list(map(lambda x: x.split(", "), foo))`

Comment: in python 3, yes. that's why a list comprehension is better

Comment: I think it's a better idea to return a `map` object rather than a `list`, because in addition to that, the result is a generator, so developers can take advantage of that.

Comment: if you can do `[[elt] for elt in seq]` you can do `([elt] for elt in seq)` which is the same as map/lambda stuff without the complexity, and has the same behaviour in python 2 or 3.